# JSON array Read first element?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I got an JSON Array for my Twitch Following user checker.
I would like to get only the first date (cause thats the newest one)
out of the array but everytime my code gets executed it just swap to the next "date" then.

How can i change this?

Code;

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ranges.RangeException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.*;



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // Twitch Follower Ticker
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                private String readAll4(Reader rd) throws IOException {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                      sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                  }

                  public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl4(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
                    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                    try {
                      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                      String jsonText = readAll4(rd);
                      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                      return json;
                    } finally {
                      is.close();
                    }
                  }

                  public void FollowerTicker() throws IOException, JSONException {
                    json = readJsonFromUrl2("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+ownerchannel+"/follows");

                    JSONArray followerarray = json.getJSONArray("follows");

                    for(int n = 0; n < followerarray.length(); n++)
                    {
                        JSONObject followertime = followerarray.getJSONObject(n);
                        String ftime = followertime.getString("created_at");


                        int maxfollows = json.getInt("_total");


                    System.out.println("Total Follows : "+maxfollows);
                    System.out.println("Loop Follow Date: "+ftime);

                    }
              }
```

edited Code;

```
                private String readAll4(Reader rd) throws IOException {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                      sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                  }

                  public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl4(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
                    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
                    try {
                      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                      String jsonText = readAll4(rd);
                      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
                      return json;
                    } finally {
                      is.close();
                    }
                  }

                  public void FollowerTicker() throws IOException, JSONException {
                    json = readJsonFromUrl2("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+ownerchannel+"/follows");

                    JSONArray followerarray = json.getJSONArray("follows");

//                  for(int n = 0; n < followerarray.length(); n++)
                    {
                        JSONObject followertime = followerarray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String ftime = followertime.getString("created_at");
                        String fname = followertime.getJSONObject("user").getString("display_name");  
                        int maxfollows = json.getInt("_total");


                    System.out.println("Total Follows zurzeit: "+maxfollows);
                    System.out.println("Neustes Follower - Datum: "+ftime);
                    System.out.println("Neuster Follower Name: "+fname);

                    }
              }
```

Comment: If you only want to get the first date, just use `followerarray.getJSONObject(0);` to get the first element in the JSONArray and don't do the loop. I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: Wow, thats exactly what im was looking for! thank you! =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just dont loop and do something like that:

```
private static int FIRST_ELEMENT = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray("[{\"Hello1\":\"1\"},{\"Hello2\":\"2\"}]");

    if (json.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("First: " + json.getJSONObject(FIRST_ELEMENT).toString());// parse the date instead of toString()
    }
}
```

iam not sure if this is exactly what you want ;)

Comment: I used the methode tonga told me and its now working the way i want it.  Thanks anyway! =)

Comment: In fact its exactly the same method but my answer was to late ;)

Comment: Oh well, i see an error now. as soon as my code gets used it prints the date + name like 30x times. its everytime the first one :o any help on fixing that?

Comment: I guess you didnt removed the for ;) `for(int n = 0; n < followerarray.length(); n++)`

Comment: oh yeah my bad :D but still theres an other thing i dont get;  As soon it posts the date+name it also posts the whole JSON :/ did update the whole code above.

Comment: Check your code for something like `System.out.println(followerarray.getJSONObject(0))` or other syso's

Comment: found it :-) May u have any hints for me how i can set up the whole thing that it will check the newest date with an older one so if theres a change it will send a message to the irc channel with the name like "Thanks for following, UserXYZ" ? :)

Comment: well i dont know the api and dont know all your code but in general this should be the workflow (not the best solution): 1. poll for the latest messages in an defined interval (if the interval is short you probably dont miss any message but i guess the api provider dont like you anymore) 2. check if the **new** latest message is newer than the **old** "latest" message (u have to save the message with every poll and compare the dates) 3. if the message is newer send a message to IRC otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Get shorter answer for free!

```
JSONObject first = new JSONArray(
    "[{\"Key1\":\"Value1\"}]").
  getJSONObject(0);
```